# How Google does animated tags in their Google+ app?

Tags: android, google-plus

I have noticed animation that occurs in Google+ app with the tags on right of any post.
Tags are animating one by one in that view in some interval.
But I can't work out how they achieve it. 
I'm just looking for some hint on how to achieve such animation in tags label view. 
[image].

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html ?